# mouse description in processing

Tags: coordinates, processing, mouseover

I'd like to add a description next to the mouse cursor while passing the mouse over a certain object in my sketch.

```
void setup ()
{
  size(400,400);
}

void draw()
{
 background(255);
 fill(150);
 rect(100,100,20,20);

 if (mousePressed)
   {

    String text= "The mouse is pressed and over the button";
    fill(0);
    text(text, mouseX+5, mouseY-5);
   }
}
```

that's the best i could do. What i want is to make the message appear when the mouse is over the button (same coordinates of the rectangular) without pressing, just brushing.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got your mouseX and mouseY coordinates.

You've also got the coordinates of your rectangle.

To check whether your mouse is inside your rectangle, you simply check whether your mouseX is in between the left and right side of the rectangle, and you check whether your mouseY is in between the top and bottom of the rectangle. If those are both true, then the mouse is inside the rectangle.

Put that logic into an if statement instead of checking the mousePressed variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to check the over event on your object:

```
if(mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 100+20 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 100+20){
    String text= "The mouse is pressed and over the button";
    fill(0);
    text(text, mouseX+5, mouseY-5);
}
```